# How to use rsyslog ltrim function?

Tags: rsyslog

I would like to trim leading and trailing spaces from the `msg` field using rsyslog.  I read it has functions called `rtrim` and `ltrim` but I can't find any explanation of how to use functions in RainierScript.  I would really appreciate if someone can show an example of these functions.  My current config is like this:

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="forward")

template(name="RFC5424_IP" type="string"
  string="<%PRI%>1 %timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %fromhost-ip% %APP-NAME% %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %msg%"
)

ruleset(name="forward") {
  action(type="omfwd"
    protocol="tcp"
    target="127.0.0.1"
    port="40514"
    Template="RFC5424_IP"
    TCP_Framing="octet-counted"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` to create a new json variable, typically of the same
name, at the top of a tree of json values, and then refer to the variable
in the template, as in the following.

```
template(name="RFC5424_IP" type="string"
  string="... %$!msg%"
)

ruleset(name="forward") {
  set $!msg = rtrim(ltrim($msg));
  action(type="omfwd"
     ...
  )
}
```

Don't forget the terminating semi-colon (;)!
See [Variable property types](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rainerscript/variable_property_types.html)